# How to sub and superscript an R leaflet plot legend

Tags: r, leaflet, superscript

How can I superscript and subscript an R leaflet legend title. For example m2 in the example below?

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview) ## for the breweries dataset


## palette for the legend
palB <- colorNumeric('Blues', seq(1,14, by = 2))

##create a leaflet plot with legend
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = breweries, color = ~palB(number.of.types)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = palB, values = breweries$number.of.types, title = "size (m2)")
```

I have tried

```
expression "'size'*' ('m'^2*')'"
```

but it just prints that

Answer (score 2):

Just use the according html tags: `title = "size (m<sup>2</sup>)"`

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview) ## for the breweries dataset

## palette for the legend
palB <- colorNumeric('Blues', seq(1,14, by = 2))

##create a leaflet plot with legend
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = breweries, color = ~palB(number.of.types)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = palB, values = breweries$number.of.types, title = "size (m<sup>2</sup>)")
```

[image]